# invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5") with modulo

Tags: bash

Put simply I would like to check if the following statement is truthy: `8 % 1.5 === 0.5`

```
secondMatch=1.5
secondMatchResult=0.5

for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
    if [[ $(($COUNTER%3)) -eq 1 ]]
    then
       FILE_CONTENTS="$FILE_CONTENTSfile 'input.mp4'"
    elif [[ $(($COUNTER%$secondMatch)) -eq $secondMatchResult ]]
    then
       FILE_CONTENTS="$FILE_CONTENTS\ninpoint 3180"
    else
       FILE_CONTENTS="$FILE_CONTENTS\noutpoint 6000\n"
    fi
    echo "$element"
done
```

The failing line with error:

```
elif [[ $(($COUNTER%$secondMatch)) -eq $secondMatchResult ]]
```

Full Error:

```
 ./cut.sh: line 36: 2%1.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")
```

n.b please ignore my bash tallents :(

Comment: bash can only do integer maths, no floats.

Comment: :O!!! My mind is blown :D How can you test modulo with the 2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th indexed item? :O

Comment: Modulo is only defined for integers, `8 % 1.5` makes no sense even outside bash.

Comment: Ye fair point..

Comment: Modulo is defined across the real numbers. You can feed your real expressions through `bc` using a "here" document with shell interpretation, and get an integer result. Read `man bc`.